# Redis memory usage, ZSET and docker

Tags: memory, docker, redis

I have a redis instance (3.2) on docker (official image) which is pretty much unused, except the script I launched every second, to unqueue potential items in a ZSET.
Here is my script:

```
local latestSchedule = redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], '-inf', 123456789, 'LIMIT', '0', '1')
if latestSchedule[1] == nil then return nil end
redis.call('ZREM', KEYS[1], latestSchedule[1])
return latestSchedule[1]
```

Even though this ZSET is most of the time empty, Redis is eating more and more memory, up to 128MB, until it restarts and goes up again.

Am I missing something?
Is redis memory usage usually growing without doing anything?
Is my script not well suited for unqueuing from a ZSET?
Should  I watch somewhere else?

As per Karthikeyan Gopall request, here is the INFO, just before it reaches 128MB:

```
# Server
redis_version:3.2.0
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:5382f69a4e75566b
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.9.2
process_id:1
run_id:4e22b73f22436677376b4d097746c2a30ba2b9bc
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:21140
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
lru_clock:6816977
executable:/data/redis-server
config_file:

# Clients
connected_clients:5
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:33392560
used_memory_human:31.85M
used_memory_rss:125399040
used_memory_rss_human:119.59M
used_memory_peak:33473544
used_memory_peak_human:31.92M
total_system_memory:1787236352
total_system_memory_human:1.66G
used_memory_lua:67447808
used_memory_lua_human:64.32M
maxmemory:134217728
maxmemory_human:128.00M
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
mem_fragmentation_ratio:3.76
mem_allocator:jemalloc-4.0.3

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:162
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1466413629
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:1
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_current_size:1039856
aof_base_size:0
aof_pending_rewrite:0
aof_buffer_length:0
aof_rewrite_buffer_length:0
aof_pending_bio_fsync:0
aof_delayed_fsync:0

# Stats
total_connections_received:21174
total_commands_processed:339098
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:10
total_net_input_bytes:34329347
total_net_output_bytes:11702705
instantaneous_input_kbps:0.96
instantaneous_output_kbps:0.14
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:24
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:200
keyspace_misses:84628
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:0
migrate_cached_sockets:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:27.75
used_cpu_user:21.72
used_cpu_sys_children:0.00
used_cpu_user_children:0.00

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=47,expires=47,avg_ttl=17584379
```

And just when it restarts:

```
# Server
redis_version:3.2.0
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:5382f69a4e75566b
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.9.2
process_id:1
run_id:4e22b73f22436677376b4d097746c2a30ba2b9bc
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:21140
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
lru_clock:6816977
executable:/data/redis-server
config_file:

# Clients
connected_clients:5
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:33392560
used_memory_human:31.85M
used_memory_rss:125399040
used_memory_rss_human:119.59M
used_memory_peak:33473544
used_memory_peak_human:31.92M
total_system_memory:1787236352
total_system_memory_human:1.66G
used_memory_lua:67447808
used_memory_lua_human:64.32M
maxmemory:134217728
maxmemory_human:128.00M
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
mem_fragmentation_ratio:3.76
mem_allocator:jemalloc-4.0.3

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:162
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1466413629
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:1
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_current_size:1039856
aof_base_size:0
aof_pending_rewrite:0
aof_buffer_length:0
aof_rewrite_buffer_length:0
aof_pending_bio_fsync:0
aof_delayed_fsync:0

# Stats
total_connections_received:21174
total_commands_processed:339098
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:10
total_net_input_bytes:34329347
total_net_output_bytes:11702705
instantaneous_input_kbps:0.96
instantaneous_output_kbps:0.14
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:24
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:200
keyspace_misses:84628
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:0
migrate_cached_sockets:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:27.75
used_cpu_user:21.72
used_cpu_sys_children:0.00
used_cpu_user_children:0.00

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=47,expires=47,avg_ttl=17584379
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of info from your redis cli terminal. Make sure you take this at the time when your ZSET is empty and memory Is around 128 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong. Here **maxmemory_human:128.00M** means the maximum memory redis can take as per your configuration (you can change this in redis.conf file, your current value will be 134217728 bytes ie, 128 MB). If your memory usage goes beyond this range, redis will start throwing out of memory error as per your eviction policy (**maxmemory_policy:noeviction**)

You need to see **used_memory_human:31.85M** for the current memory used by redis.

```
# Keyspace
db0:keys=47,expires=47,avg_ttl=17584379
```

With 46 more keys in your server I guess this is a normal memory.

You can see more details about each values in info command in this link http://redis.io/commands/INFO.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help Karthikeyan Gopall.
I setup the max memory myself, so I know it's a limit that should not be reached.
That said, I wasn't expecting it to take so much space for so little number of keys.
I will look into the eviction policy and might setup different instances then :).